# NullPointer Exception while calling webservice in play framework

Tags: java, web-services, playframework

Anything wrong in this program ?

I am getting `nullPointerException` while calling web service in play framework in version 2.4.3.

```
package com.enkindle.box;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import play.libs.ws.WSClient;

/**
 * @author thirumal
 *
 */
public class Sample {

@Inject WSClient ws;   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.callAPI();
}

public void callAPI() {
    ws.url("www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/").get();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `Sample` class is not available within the context of your dependency injection - I'm assuming Guice.  There are a couple ways to tackle this but the easiest is to create a `Sample` interface and bind its implementation, `SampleImpl`, using Guice so that it will be available for injected dependencies.  I'm going to assume that this gets spawned from a controller, so you could inject `Sample` into your controller and hit the `callApi()` method from there.

Controller:

```
public class SampleController extends Controller {
    @Inject Sample sample;

    public Promise<Result> apiCall() {
        sample.callApi();
        return promise(() -> ok());
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
@ImplementedBy(SampleImpl.class)
public interface Sample {
    public void callApi();
}
```

And the interface implementation:

```
public class SampleImpl implements Sample {
    @Inject WSClient ws;

    @Override
    public void callApi() {
        // ws should not be null
        ws.url("www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/").get();
    }
}
```

Reference docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Binding-annotations

Comment: Or he could just extend Controller. But it's good to code against an interface.