# Play 2.5.3: Using dependency injection to get configuration values

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.5

I'm trying to migrate a Playframework application from 2.4 to 2.5.3 and I have problems to get values from `application.conf` file:

**Before** to get a value of from `application.conf` what I do was:

```
Play.application().configuration().getString("label")
```

**Now** as `Play.application()` is deprecated, I should use Dependency injection. Based on the [framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDependencyInjection) I use the following instructions:

1. **Define import**: import `javax.inject.*; import play.Configuration;`
2. **Define class property**: `@Inject private Configuration configuration;`
3. **Use the configuration class property on my class**

When I follow these instructions on my controller `Application.java` it is working perfectly:

But when I try to use it on an other class object from my project, the dependency injection is not working and I always get a `NullPointerException`.

Can someone give me an example about how to get values from `application.conf` using dependency Injection?

Some part of my java code where I try to use the DI:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import play.Configuration;
import play.Logger;

public class Zipper {

    @Inject private  Configuration configuration;

    public void unZip(String zipFilePath) {
        Logger.debug("Display : zipFilePath"+zipFilePath);
        Logger.debug("before call parameter from application.conf");
        Logger.debug("configuration.getString = "+configuration.getString("Unzipedfile.path"));
        Logger.debug("aftercall parameter from application.conf");
    }
}
```

And I always get a null pointer exception, at the line  with `configuration.getString("Unzipedfile.path")`

Comment: Post the code that isn't working.

Comment: i have updated as requested. <br> The same kind of code is working on my controller application.java, but never on my other java classes.

Comment: You cannot inject into arbitrary classes that have not been created by DI themselves or have not been introduced to the Guice context.  If your class Zipper was created by Guice or injected somewhere, then you would have the context to inject. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32896354/1956540

Comment: yes, you're totaly right, it was my error, i put some details below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put here the answer, in order to help anyone with the same issue

My error came from the way i used to instantiate my Zipper java class from my calling class.

Thx to Igmar Palsenberg, he provided me the answer :
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/play-framework/uLFqTM9_Iy4

I used **Zipper zipTest = new Zipper();** to instanciate my Zipper class and i have to use **Zipper zipTest = injector.instanceOf(Zipper.class);**

Comment: Is your class caller a test?

Comment: nop, just an helper layer and zipper class was an util class, my understanding is that when i use  Zipper zipTest = new Zipper() , i loose Dependency Injection mecanism. in order to keep it i have to use  injector.instanceOf instead of new

Comment: So, why are you not injecting `Zipper` into that class instead?

Comment: because my target was to update my code from 2.4 to 2.5.3 and be able to reach parameters from application.conf from all my classes where i need it. Moreover the Dependency Injection is a new pattern for me.. unknown before last Sunday.... Now my code is working, i have to refactor it, to really fit the DI pattern.

Comment: Using dependency injection only at part of the code will make it harder. I mean, you will have two way of instantiate objects. That sounds more complicate to me.

Comment: i'm agree, :) i know i will have to refactor my code.

Comment: I'm asking because there are two possible ways you get the `application` object used to instantiate `Zipper`. 1) you are using `Play.application()` which is deprecated or 2) You are injecting an `Application`. If you are doing 2, why not directly inject `Zipper` instead? ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I think that you can initialize the configuration like this:

```
private  Configuration configuration = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(Configuration .class);
```

So, your Zipper will be:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import play.Configuration;
import play.Logger;

public class Zipper {

    private  Configuration configuration = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(Configuration .class);

    public void unZip(String zipFilePath) {
        Logger.debug("Display : zipFilePath"+zipFilePath);
        Logger.debug("before call parameter from application.conf");
        Logger.debug("configuration.getString = "+configuration.getString("Unzipedfile.path"));
        Logger.debug("aftercall parameter from application.conf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with constructor injection instead:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import play.Configuration;
import play.Logger;

public class Zipper {

    private Configuration configuration;

    @Inject
    public Zipper(Configuration config) {
        this.configuration = config;
    }

    public void unZip(String zipFilePath) {
        Logger.debug("Display : zipFilePath"+zipFilePath);
        Logger.debug("before call parameter from application.conf");
        Logger.debug("configuration.getString = "+configuration.getString("Unzipedfile.path"));
        Logger.debug("aftercall parameter from application.conf");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure that Guice is capable of inject `private` fields. Anyway, constructor injection is the recommended injection type.

Comment: i have seen this way, but it not seems to fit my need.

Comment: i have seen this way, but it not seems to fit my need. because if i update my constructor, that means that on my calling java class , i will have to initiate this new parameter, no ? with a stuff like that Zipper zipTest = new Zipper(conf) and conf will have to be initiate in my calling java class, I would like avoid this situation, and in this case injection on Zipper class is not useful, no ? may be i'm wrong, can you show me how call the zipper class with your proposal ?

Comment: moreover, as i said inject private fields is working with controller application.java , i have this issue only on all the other java classes

Comment: How are you using `Zipper` class? Could you please edit your question to how where it is being instantiated and used?

Comment: thx for your help, i finally found my error and put details below

Answer (score 1):

you should try to remove `private`.
use:

```
@Inject Configuration configuration;
```

instead of:

```
@Inject private  Configuration configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotate your class with Singleton so that play can detect your bean to inject your resources.