# how to read the application conf before application is started with play framework 2.5.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I need to read the application.conf file to a module which is started by addding

```
 enabled += play.modules.globalModule.
```

However, in this module,i need to read the db connection string and do preparations before application is started. But go the error below:

```
Couldn't instantiate DBHeloper
There is no started application
```

I tried this in both dev and prod environments with the following commands but none worked.

```
 run
 sbt stage
 sbt testProd
```

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the `play.Configuration` on your module so you will be able to access it.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972305/play-2-5-3-using-dependency-injection-to-get-configuration-values) there is a complete example on how to do that.

Comment: The module currently uses a scala OBJECT DBHelper to read the connection strings. Do i have to rename the object to class in order to inject the configuration into it? If so there will be too many changes. Do you have any better advice?

Comment: Just use the configuration object that play already gives you, I dont know htis DBHelper. If you really wanna do it via the DBHelper you should inject the DBHelper on your module via DI.